# JavaScript & self executing functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to understand (probably simple concepts) about JS, and I've put together the below piece of code to explain what I don't get. What I do not understand is where the name variable is stored. Is that variable now global?

```
(function($) {

  var name = '';

  $.helloWorld = function(yourName) {
    name = yourName;
    console.log("Hello " + yourName);
  }

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: The variable is scoped to that closure, that's the point of IIFEs, to encapsulate code and not leak variables to the outer scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name` variable is local to the outer function, because it's declared with the `var` keyword. The inner function is a closure that contains a reference to that variable. Here's a better example that shows this off:

```
(function($) {

  var name = '';

  $.setName = function(newName) {
    name = newName;
  }

  $.showName = function() {
    console.log("Name is: " + name);

}(jQuery));
```

After defining this, you can do:

```
$.setName("Larry");
$.showName();
$.setName("Fred");
$.showName();
```

See [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111200#111200)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I access the name variable from the helloWorld function? Is there some way à la Java's this keyword?

Comment: You would access it by referring to it by name (just like any other variable).  You could have your helloWorld function print its value like this: `alert(name);`

Comment: Alright, so I should also avoid using inner function argument names which conflicts with outer function variable names since I can't really distinguish them from each other like you can with Java?

Comment: Yes. These are just nested function scopes, not objects.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Marking this one as the right answer as it was both the first answer and apparently a correct answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

This should help you understand:

```
(function(){

    var name;
    var scope1;

    // Here you can use scope1 and name

    (function(){

        var name;  //  <------------------------
        var scope2;                         // |
                                            // |
        // Here you can use scope1,scope2, and name

        (function(){

            var name;   //  <------------------------------
            var scope3;                                 // |
                                                        // |
            // Here you can use scope1,scope2,scope3, and name

        })();

     })();

})();

// Any\variable declared outside of any function scope is in the global scope.
// A variable declared here can be accessed by window.name from any scope
var name = 5;
```

So in this snippet, 3 scopes are created by the three functions and in the innermost you can access the variables that have unique names (scope1,scope2, and scope3) as well as the local variable `name`, which is a separate name from the one it the middle scope. Reusing variable names like that to prevent access to the variable in an outer scope is called shadowing.

Note that a variable that is not declared with the `var` keyword is auotmatically assumed to be in the global scope. It is a bad practice to declare many variables in the global scope as they can easily conflict with other scripts.

Comment: Thanks for fleshing it out a little. Upvoting your effort!